# sql: how can I copy the value from a table into another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table PLANE_MODEL:

```
PLANE_MODEL(NUMBER model_id, NUMBER capacity)
```

and a table FLIGHT:

```
FLIGHT ( NUMBER flight_id,NUMBER available_seats)
```

I want to copy the value capacity of PLANE_MODEL as the initial value in available_seats of FLIGHT. How can I do this?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Where do you record which plane model is going to be used on the flight ID?  Without that, we can't help...

Comment: Do you want to insert a new row or update an existing row?

Comment: Is this the same basic question as your last one ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707979/)? Or you looking for alternatives to the trigger approach? Edited to add: and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703040/

Answer (score 2):

To create a FLIGHT record for a particular flight (1234) using a model (918), you can use the below

```
insert into FLIGHT ( flight_id, available_seats )
SELECT 1234, capacity
FROM PLANE_MODEL
WHERE model_id = 918
```

Comment: +1 because this answer seems right but got downvoted without any comment.